# Load images into a vector of vector of Mat - vector<vector<Mat>>

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on an image processing project using opencv C++ library. I have been able to read image names and load images from a folder into my code using `glob()` function. The problem I have is how to organize the images in a two-dimensional array fashion (row-column fashion). ***I want to load 10 images per individual for 100 individual and store them in a `MAT` array/vector*** such that my subjects are represented by rows and images for each subject are the columns.

This code is throwing unhandled exception error.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
String folder = "E:\\Face Databases\\FG-NET DATASET\\images\\*.JPG";
vector<String> filenames;
int start = folder.find("*");//get the start of the real image label
//cout << "Position = " << start << endl;
glob(folder, filenames, false);
String label[1001];
ofstream labels;
labels.open("labels.csv");

vector<vector<Mat>> myImage;

for (size_t i = 0; i < filenames.size(); ++i)
{
    vector<Mat> myImage = imread(filenames[i]);
    label[i] = filenames[i].substr(start, 6);
    labels << label[i] << "\n";//write labels to a csv file
}
waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You seem to know what you want, so... Kindly show *what you tried*, and postulate where things seemed to go wrong.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please remember to look at the [How to Ask guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjv3Kiep4HMAhWEMyYKHSXJCRwQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-ask&usg=AFQjCNEDXp3Jt0aiEKFPFI03PFSjhs3gAw&sig2=aQoL-Q1QCDgWPtjQ2CEVeA&bvm=bv.119028448,d.eWE) before asking questions. You will lose your reputation.

Comment: Thank you for the remainder. I have added my opencv newbie code

Answer (score 0):

the statement

```
vector<Mat> myImage = imread(filenames[i]);
```

should be

```
cv::Mat myImage = imread(filenames[i]);
```

`imread()` returns `Mat` object.

Also verify `filenames[i]` is valid image file path.